# Possible to VNC/RDP into Docker Windows Containers with GPU passthrough?

Tags: docker

Use-case: Automated QA of video games

Within the past 6 months it seems Microsoft and Docker have put a lot of effort to enable GPU passthrough for docker windows containers.

- [GPU Acceleration.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/gpu-acceleration)
- [GPU example console docker app.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-container-samples/directx)

It would hugely benefit us if we could launch our games in docker and connect to them via RDP/VNC/teamviewer/whatever to view and interact with the game in real-time (low FPS is fine) as needed.

It would seem all the ingredients could be here to do so, but my Googling and Docker inexperience has left me stumped. Primarily because it seems that whilst some attempts have been made they were done over 2 years ago, before Microsoft implemented a lot of the more recent features.

I've been able to launch a docker container, but little more than that. How can I get some kind of remote desktop/monitor service running and give it a go?

Cheers!